# Symfony 2 configuration page has no styling

Tags: php, symfony, config

I have a very straightforward question for which I can't find the answer to here on stackoverflow.

I am learning Symfony2. I am having problems with the web/config.php page (right at the beginning, so not a good start) - all the text loads up but it has no styling (like one sees in the tutorials on the Symfony site. Despite researching this particular problem I have been unable to find an answer

Any help on this rudimentary question would be appreciated - as I have just begun, I am unsure of what other information I can provide, however I am guessing that this is something someone has experienced before. (

Comment: Can you open the css-file? Maybe you can see an error?

Comment: Do you got informations from firebug or similar tools for your browser if some css and js files are not found ?

Comment: app/console assets:install.  You either moved your web directory or you did not use composer install which kicks off some install scripts.  The css will end up under web/bundles.

Comment: Do you have inside your /web folder these paths : bundles/framework/css/  and  bundles/sensiodistribution/webconfigurator/css  
In there should be your config.php css files

Comment: Hi Andreas - no there are no such files in the web folder. In fact, I can't see any css files in the application at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It just seems like you haven't correctly installed the static assets.

From your shell

```
$ cd /path/to/project
$ php app/console assets:install web

# Alternatively, if you're using a filesystem that supports symbolic links
$ php app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

then refresh the config page - that should do it.